# CSS grid with fixed-width larger than content

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a simple CSS grid, with one cell - an `<img>`. The grid has a fixed width of `100px` and uses `grid-auto-columns: 100%;` to scale the image down to fit inside:

```css
.grid {
    display: grid;
    width: 100px;
    grid-auto-columns: 100%;

    background-color: #844;
}

.grid > * {
    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class='grid'>
  <img src='https://i.imgur.com/HAwaW3D.png' />
</div>
```

But for some reason, the grid's height remains as if the image was rendered at its original size, leaving this empty space after the cell:

[image: screenshot]

And I cannot for the life of me find a way to avoid it.

Any ideas on how to make the grid's height match its contents in this scenario?

---

note: I'm testing in Firefox 56.2.5

Comment: which browser?.

Comment: @TemaniAfif FF 56

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website / demo doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: old version, we are actually at V66, you should probably update, not able to reproduce

Comment: hmm, yeah i see the current version is doing something different… i'll see if i can get it working there at least; thanks